# Merge Two CSV Files by Column (Rather than Inserting New Lines)

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I created two batch files:

1:

```
dir *.txt %t *.* /w/a/b/-p/o:gen | find "/">rezultate.csv
```

It gets the path and size and date and creation time of all text files from a directory and exports the result into a CSV file.

2:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist results.csv del results.csv
for %%f in (D:\script\*.txt) do (
    set i=0
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%l in (%%f) do (
        set /A i+=1
        set line!i!=%%l
    )
    echo %%f, !line1!, !line2!,>> D:\script\results.csv
)
```

It gets the file path and what the file contains on the first 2 lines(also text files) from a specified directory and exports the result into a CSV file.

I attempted to combine the batch files and I managed to export the result from both batch files into the same CSV file but the output from the first batch file is exported on the first 5 lines and the output from the second batch file is exported on the next 5 lines.

I would like to merge the batch files so that the output can be exported from the first batch file wich will have one column and 5 lines and in the same CSV to export the output from the second batch file wich has 3 columns but not under the export of the first batch.I would like the CSV to have still 5 lines but 4 columns.
I also attempted to merge the CSV files with another batch file but I get the same result.

Please help with a solution if possible because I looked for solutions for more than one week...

Here's how I need the CSV file to look:

[image]

Final result will have to be like this:

[image: final result]

Thanks for your help @dohaqatar7.

Here are the results that I reached today.
You were right about your asumption regarding the way I would like to merge the CSV files.

1:

I went for you're script for part 1 as it was more acurrate and I changed it a little bit and it will be like this:

`@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do echo %%~ta,%%~za>>results.csv`

Sample output[image: sample]

2:

I will remain with my script as it returns exactly what I want and it is accurate.

`@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (D:\script\*.txt) do (
    set i=0
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%l in (%%f) do (
        set /A i+=1
        set line!i!=%%l
    )
    echo %%f, !line1!, !line2!,>>D:\script\results.csv
)`

sample output [image: sample]

You have a sample also with the final result.

As for the script provided to merge the CSV files I was not able to make it work as it does not return the output in a new CSV file.Could you please change it a little bit so that I can use it.I hope I explained better right now.I would have given more details but I'm new around here and I'm limited by my reputation.

It would have been great if you could insert the path wich is "D:\scrip\filename\" but I can do that myself.

Kind regards,

Comment: The script now places output in a new CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't know that your first piece of code does what you say it does. When I run it, the file always remains empty. This code does what you claim the first pieces does.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do echo %%~ta,%%~za,%%~fa
```

If your code works for you, keep using it. If you start having issues with it, this code will work.

---

As for combining CSV files, I am a little uncertain about what you want. Here is what I assumed.

You want to take `a.csv`

```
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
```

and `b.csv`

```
d1
d2
```

and combine them into `ab.csv`

```
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,b2,c2,d2
```

This code will take two arguments, the files to combine, and output the result to a new file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "line1=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
    set "file1[!line1!]=%%a"
    set /a line1+=1
)

set "line2=0"
for /f "tokens=*"  %%a in (%2) do (
    set "file2[!line2!]=%%a"
    set /a line2+=1
)

if !line1! GTR !line2! (
    set /a max=!line1!-1
) else (
    set /a max=!line2!-1
)

set "mergedCSV=%~n1_%~n2.csv"

echo.>%mergedCSV%
for /l %%a in (0,1,%max%) do (
    if "!file1[%%a]!"=="" (
        echo !file2[%%a]! >> %mergedCSV%
    ) else (
        if "!file2[%%a]!"=="" (
            echo !file1[%%a]! >> %mergedCSV%
        ) else (
            echo !file1[%%a]!,!file2[%%a]! >> %mergedCSV%
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout


    On Error Resume Next
    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = Fso.OpenTextFile(Arg(1), 1, false)
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Outp.WriteLine "Error: " & err.number & " " & err.description & " from " & err.source
        err.clear
        wscript.exit
    End If
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream And File.AtEndOfStream
    Line = ""
    Line2 = ""
        Line=Inp.readline
        Line2=File.readline
        outp.writeline Line & "," & Line2   
    Loop
```

To use on screen

```
cscript //nologo <"path to script.vbs"> "" "c:\file1.txt" < "c:\file2.txt"
```

To put in a file

```
cscript //nologo <"path to script.vbs"> "" "c:\file1.txt" < "c:\file2.txt" > "file3.txt"
```